# How do I print values after all the input has been taken from user? (without storing the input values)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have to print a large amount of values, and can't store them in a list/tuple etc because i get a Time Limit Exceeded in the output (time limit is 1 sec).

the question:

```
Given an array of n integers, your task is to process q queries of the form: 
what is the sum of values in range [a,b]?
```

input:

```
The first input line has two integers n and q: the number of values and queries.
The second line has n integers x1,x2,…,xn: the array values.
Finally, there are q lines describing the queries. Each line has two integers a and b: 
what is the sum of values in range [a,b]?
```

input format:

```
8 4
3 2 4 5 1 1 5 3
2 4
5 6
1 8
3 3
```

My approach:

```
n, q = map(int, input().split())
ls = list(map(int, input().split()))
ls1 = []
for i in range(q):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    ls1.append(sum(ls[a-1:b]))
for i in ls1:
    print(i)
```

I need to be able to compute the values and not store them in the list as I think that is what's causing the TLE. Any help is apprecieated

Comment: Is there a reason you're appending the result of `sum` to `ls1`, then going back through and printing from `ls1` rather than printing it out directly?

Comment: yes, the output is supposed to be given after all the input is taken from the user @HenryEcker

Comment: Over what part of tbe program does the time limit apply? Summing and storing a few numbers is trivial and ultra fast. If user input is inside tbe timed section then I'd suspect that. Printing can also be slow, much slower than summing or storing

Comment: It's for the whole code. @dpwr

Comment: The number of input elements is 10^9 and the size of each element can be 10^6, I think storing the elements in the list is whats causing the tle

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: [CSES - Range Sum Queries In Python](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/cses-range-sum-queries-in-python/81333/9)

Comment: Does the exception go away if you _stop_ storing the values, but still read the correct amount of input and write the correct amount of output? (Not the correct output values, but the same amount of output so the only timing that changes is the storage). I expect it won't; it's much more likely that it's I/O behind your performance issues.

Comment: @HenryEcker oh! i shouldve thought of prefix sums lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n, q = map(int, input().split())
ls1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
prefix = [0]
for i in range(n):
    prefix.append(prefix[-1] + ls1[i])
print(prefix)
for i in range(q):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    print(prefix[b]-prefix[a-1])
```

Solved by using prefix sums

Answer (score 1):

1. Use prefix sums to speed up sum calculation
2. Store all answers in a single string and print the string in the end

This should speed up your execution significantly.

```py
n,q = map(int, input().split())
l = list(map(int, input().split()))
range_sum = [0]*n
range_sum[0] = l[0]
for i in range(1,n):
    range_sum[i] = range_sum[i-1]+l[i]
ans = ""
for _ in range(q):
    a,b = map(int, input().split())
    if a==0:
        ans += str(range_sum[b]) + "\n"
    else:
        ans += str(range_sum[b]-range_sum[a-1]) + "\n"
print(ans)
```